# using predict_model: NameError: name 'prep_pipe' is not defined"

Tags: model, predict, pycaret

I am trying to load a saved model and then using predict_model function in order to score the data but getting the below error

> NameError: name 'prep_pipe' is not defined"

The version of pycaret==2.3.10

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the same environment that you used to create the model when you load the model back. It may be possible that your environment used for model creation is not the same as the one you are using to load the model now.